# Heating of two identical balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity

You are given two identical steel balls of radius (say) 5 cm. One ball is resting on a table, the other ball is hanging from a string. Both balls are heated (with a blow torch) until their radii have increased to the same value of 5.01 cm. Which ball absorbed more heat and why?

Comment: Equal for the two. Thermal expansion of volume is connected to the temperature change - not the position in space.

Comment: @Steeven think of the motion of each ball's CM (I know, negligible but that's probably what the question is getting at)

Comment: Aha, @NeuroFuzzy! Nice one.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy - I encourage you to write that as an answer, perhaps elaborating slightly on the work done against gravity ("heat is work" and all that).

Comment: It's with some reluctance I VTC this as homework, since it's a clever question, but homework it blatantly is.

Comment: As @JohnRennie says, this is a great question, but clearly homework. If you can write up your thoughts on the problem and show where you are having trouble, there will be some fun answers

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance, I have trouble is what I have asked. I clearly need to know which ball absorbs heat more and why?

Comment: And (@to everyone who put this on hold) giving the reason- "Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users". Tell me how can it be made **on-topic?**. If you think this post still needs to get  better, then why don't someone **edit it** and make it **on-topic**.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the heat absorbed becomes internal energy, while the other part becomes gravitational potential energy. The gravitational energy of the two balls changes in opposite ways when the radius is increased. Then to make the two balls have the same internal energy, different amounts of heat are needed...

Answer (score 0):

Not-so-great question from the prof.

What is the table made of?

If the table is 1cm thick brass it would absorb quite a bit of heat from the ball resting on it (and also be quite an awesome table). If it is glass there will be very little heat transfer. If there is a block of aerogel or space shuttle tile under the ball there will be nearly zero conductive loss, and not that much convective loss as the table will obstruct the airflow far more than the free-hanging one.

A 10cm steel ball weighs about 4kg - if the string breaks (or catches on fire) and it lands on the table it will have the same heat loss as the one already there. If the glass table breaks after being smacked by a big steel ball falling on it you will have 2 hot balls of metal on the floor, also sharing the same thermal conditions. If it rolls off the brass table and finds a quiet corner with no airflow it may retain more heat than the table-dwelling sphere.

Comment: It is immaterial. Question is which ball has absorbed more heat